# Help translating Japanese postcard

Tags: translation

I am trying to identify, date and publisher details of an old (probably c1904) postcard. Can anybody help translate the writing on front (top and bottom of card) and also the writing on back. Thanks, David.[image]

Comment: [Naniwa Dance (Naniwa odori) from Ehagaki sekai | Museum of Fine Arts, Boston](https://www.mfa.org/collections/object/naniwa-dance-naniwa-odori-from-ehagaki-sekai-403555)

Answer (score 1):

The reverse writing (righttoleft) is 郵便はがき、“postal service postcard”.

The top is the title, なにはおどり、“the dances of Naniwa”.

The bottom is the edition reference, 滑{こっ}稽{けい}新聞社發行、“Kokkei Newspaper Agency Edition”. 社 is given with its left radical in its original form, 示。

Comment: 社 is given with its left radical in its original form, 示,  i.e.: 社